# Single word to differentiate animal that likes everyone vs. "one-person dog"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is the English word that means "likes everyone" (as opposed to being attached to one person)?

Comment: Amiable? Friendly? Well-disposed? We'll need a little more context than this.

Comment: A "friendly" dog is usually understood to mean that it will allow itself to be approached by people other than its owner, or other animals.

Answer (score 1):

'Gregarious' is the word for a person who likes lots of, and a variety of, human company. I see no reason why it should not be applied to a dog.

Comment: Nice word! And also, this word was originally used to specify animals that live in flocks. It is originated from the latin word "grex" that means "herd, flock".  
Though it also used in biology to describe animals that tends to form a group with others of the same species.

Comment: Ya beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, "friendly" is the most common word used to describe a dog, person or other animal who likes everyone. "Oh don't worry, he's a friendly dog..."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a ***[promiscuous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promiscuous)*** pet

> not restricted to one class, sort, or person :  indiscriminate

Comment: PRoblem w/ that word is that it's got a strong sexual connotation, at least in the USA.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft And that's what makes it interesting. Picture a male dog who is happy to show his enthusiasm to just about anyone's leg.

Comment: That's just a male dog that some dooofus failed to neuter.  Bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **sociable** fits. It means amicable or companionable and would suit a friendly dog.